# oracle error: "column not allowed here"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Personn (
     pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     iname VARCHAR(50),
     gender CHAR(1),
     dateOfBirth DATE,
CONSTRAINT person_gender
CHECK (Gender BETWEEN 'f' AND 'm')  
  );

INSERT INTO Personn VALUES ('1005','john', 'M', 24/apr/1999 );
```

```
Error starting at line : 18 in command -
INSERT INTO Personn VALUES ('1005','john', 'M', 24/apr/1999 )
Error at Command Line : 18 Column : 52
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Why is the `check` statement `gender between 'f' and 'm'` rather than `gender in ('f', 'm')`?  Allowing genders such as `'j'` and `'l'` seems counter-intuitive (although allowing more than two values for gender is reasonable, those don't seem like reasonable values).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should change your insert statement. Date values should be given as string literals.

So change

```
INSERT INTO Personn VALUES ('1005','john', 'M', 24/apr/1999 );
```

to

```
INSERT INTO Personn VALUES (1005, 'john', 'M', '24/apr/1999');
```

Since your primary key is an integer, you can leave out the single quotes there.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO Personn VALUES ('1005','john', 'm', to_date('24/apr/1999', 'dd/mon/yyyy') );
```

Comment: be aware of 'M' is not 'm' for check constraint.

Comment: @Jeffrey: CHECK (Gender BETWEEN 'f' AND 'm') --- check is with small letters.

Comment: sorry about that - I didn't notice that you had commented on your own answer. Why not edit your answer directly?

Answer (score 2):

It's best not to assume the date format has been set to any particular value in the user's session - otherwise you're likely to hit unexpected bugs later on.

Instead, use a date literal in this case:

```
INSERT INTO Personn VALUES ('1005','john', 'M', DATE '1999-04-24');
```

In addition, if the order of the columns change in the future (this can happen when the schema is rebuilt), it's safer to have the columns enumerated, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO Personn (pid, iname, gender, dateofbirth)
VALUES (1005,'john', 'm', DATE '1999-04-24');
```

*EDIT: fixed the literals for pid and gender*

Answer (score 0):

date should be put within quotes
try this

```
INSERT INTO Personn VALUES ('1005','john', 'M', '24/apr/1999')
```